# How to fix [types removal] Specifying types in search requests is deprecated."] (elasticsearch 7.4.0 ,spring boot 2.2.6)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm developing my first application that uses elasticsearch (7.4.0) as database and I use for that spring data elasticsearch ( spring boot version is 2.2.6),every thing is working fine but I still get the following warning logs messages when I run my app.

```
Using include_type_name in put mapping requests is deprecated. The parameter will be removed in the next major version."]
[types removal] Specifying types in search requests is deprecated."]
```

I know about types removal since 7.0.0 version ,but how can I fix that ,I mean should I change my spring boot version or my elasticsearch version,how can I remove those warning messages ? Will ignoring those warnings impact the application process ?

Comment: You are trying to set the `include_type_name` parameter which [results in the warming](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/removal-of-types.html), can you share your `PUT` body?

Comment: the request is generated by spring data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot 2.2.6 pulls in Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2. and the Elasticsearch client libraries in version 6.8.7. This cannot work with an Elasticsearch cluster running version 7. You will need the Elasticsearch client libraries in at least version 7.4.0 and Spring Data Elasticsearch in version 4.0

You can do two things:

1. Explicitly specify the versions of Spring Data (realease train *Neumann* contains Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0)  and Elasticsearch to use by setting the properties in your pom.xml [see the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#dependencies):

```
    <properties>
        <elasticsearch.version>7.4.0</elasticsearch.version>
        <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Neumann-RELEASE</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
    </properties>
```

2. Use Spring Boot 2.3. This will pull in Spring Data in the same version as above and Elasticsearch client libraries in version 7.6 - which will work with you 7.4 cluster.

I'd prefer to use the second.

Comment: What do you mean when you state that "This cannot work with an Elasticsearch cluster running version 7"? I'm in the same situation as well, but to me it looks like this is only a warning - our tests indicate that queries still works as expected.

Comment: one of the breaking changes I recall when switching to 7 was the returning of the number of total hits (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/breaking-changes-7.0.html#hits-total-now-object-search-response). When using 6.x client libs to parse a 7 response there will always be 0 returned for the total hits. So you may not have encountered any problems, but there were quite some changes in the libs and API